# append div before writing to DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I am using `html +=` to write html to the DOM in a for loop.

Depending on the ID of the current item in the loop, sometimes i don't want to write a new item but instead append a section of the one just written.

This is what i'm trying but doesn't append as it should. Can I do it this way or is there a better way?

```
var html = '';
var i=0, length=data.length, image;

var lastID = '';

for(; i<length; i++) {

image = data[i];

    if(image.itemID!=lastID){   

        html += '<li>';
        html += '<div id="holder'+image.itemID+'">';
        html += '<div class="row">'+image.comment+'</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</li>';

    } else {

       $('#holder'+image.itemID).append('<div class="row">'+image.comment+'</div>');

    }

var lastID = image.itemID;

}

$('#display').append(html);
```

Comment: why aren't you initializing `i` in the for loop and re-initializing `lastWish` every loop yet not doing anything with it?

Comment: ^^ That's often considered good practice to initialize all variables at the beginning of the function

Comment: JavaScript has no block scope, but that doesn't mean it's good practice per se. But that's a different discussion altogether ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The code in the `else` section does not work because the previously created `div` is not in the DOM yet. And as long as it is not in the DOM, it is impossible to to find it querying the DOM model, e.g. with jQuery.

Unless there are issues with performance, you can insert `li` elements into DOM as soon as they are created rather then doing it all in one go. This way you will be able to find previously created elements and append content to them:

```
var i=0, length=data.length, image;

var lastID = '';

for(; i<length; i++) {

    image = data[i];

    if(image.itemID!=lastID){   

        var html = '<li>';
        html += '<div id="holder'+image.itemID+'">';
        html += '<div class="row">'+image.comment+'</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</li>';

        $('#display').append(html);

    } else {

       $('#holder'+image.itemID).append('<div class="row">'+image.comment+'</div>');

    }

    var lastWish = image.wishlist_id;
}
```

**Update**. Actually you can query and even manipulate your newly created html before it is inserted into the DOM. jQuery handles such scenarios like `$(html).find('selector')` well enough:

```
var html = ''
var i=0, length=data.length, image;

var lastID = '';

for(; i<length; i++) {

    image = data[i];

    if(image.itemID!=lastID){   

        html += '<li>';
        html += '<div id="holder'+image.itemID+'">';
        html += '<div class="row">'+image.comment+'</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</li>';

    } else {

       $(html).find('#holder'+image.itemID).append('<div class="row">'+image.comment+'</div>');

    }

    var lastWish = image.wishlist_id;
}

$('#display').append(html);
```

Comment: Thanks, the second option looks like it should work but simply doesn't. No errors in console (firebug), is there anywhere else I can check to see why it's not happening?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, apologies, it turns out to be a little bit more complicated. After `$(html)` you are creating a new object, and then `append` on it works, but does not update the initial `html` object. So two options here: either maintain jQuery object all the way, or perform transformations 'html string' -> 'jQuery object' -> 'html string' inside `else` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Append takes as an argument a jQuery object. So the proper syntax would be:

```
$('#display').append($(html));
```

Comment: actually, that's not correct. It can take an html string or an html element as well, as long as the closing elements are included.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how it can be done using a temporary element outside the DOM to manage newly created elements.

```
for(var i       = 0,
        length  = data.length,
        $el     = $('<ul>'),
        lastId, image; i < length; i++) {

    image = data[i];

    if(image.itemID !== lastId) {
        $el.append('<li><div id="holder' + image.itemID +
            '"><div class="row">' + image.comment + '</div></div></li>');
    } else {
        $el.find('#holder' + image.itemID).append('<div class="row">' + image.comment + '</div>');
    }

    lastId = image.itemID; // is that right?! cause you need to set lastId somewhere..
}

$('#display').append($el.children());
```

The problem was probably because you were trying to fetch an element (`'#holder' + image.itemID`) from the DOM before you appended it to it.